# Memoir: Remove indentation in abstract

Tags: indentation, abstract

I would like to automatically remove the indentation at the beginning of an abstract in `memoir`. I have seen [such solutions for other classes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/1603/44413). If I insert `\noindent` manually like this:

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

    \begin{abstract}
        \noindent
        \lipsum[1]    
    \end{abstract}

\end{document}
```

Then the indentation is removed completely:
[image]
I tried to modify `\abstracttextfont`, but a small indentation remains:

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\renewcommand{\abstracttextfont}{\normalfont\small\noindent}

\begin{document}

    \begin{abstract}
        \lipsum[1]    
    \end{abstract}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is probably simplest to just use

```
\renewcommand{\abstracttextfont}{\normalfont\small\noindent\ignorespaces}
```